# Did the Romans Hold Territory in Ukraine?

Tags: roman-empire, ukraine

I noticed on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimius_Severus) for Septimius Severus the map of the empire in 210 shows area around Odessa and Yuzhne. Did the Romans actually hold these areas as colonies or incorporated into a province at all? Or is Wikipedia messing with me?

Comment: Is there a reason to question the existing narrative?

Comment: I want to know why Wikipedia specifies those regions as being part of the Roman Empire. I'm not saying they're wrong, I just want to know if the Romans were there and if so how much influence they had.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Crimea for more Wikitruth.

Comment: @kimchilover, question is about continental Northern Black Seas coast, not Crimea. Btw, AetherMaster, can you rephrase question title to specifiy the region?

Comment: They sure did, but it was still called The Ukraine back then.

Comment: Most of the areas on the map are in the North Caucasus or Crimea. Maybe Odessa is in the Ukraine but not the rest. The title confused me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two areas appear to be [Olbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbia_(archaeological_site)) and [Tyras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyras). They both formed a part of the Roman province of Lower [Moesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moesia) (or "Moesia Inferior").

It is, perhaps, a little easier to see the detail on this earlier map from the Wikipedia page on the [History of the Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Roman_Empire), showing the Roman Empire at its greatest extent under the Emperor Trajan:

[image: Roman empire in AD117]

- (Source [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Roman_Empire_Trajan_117AD.png))